# Count by formula on php

Tags: php, loops, math, formula

I want to ask your help. I don't remember the Math, but I need to count by formula

[image: You can see the formula in the picture]

I am going to make the loops like that.

```
$incomeDepositDay = $totalSum * $percent / ($typePerm *100);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $term; $i++) {
    $incomeDepositTax = $percent/100 * $typePerm * ($totalSum * $i + ($incomeDepositDay * (1 - 13/100))); 
}
```

But I see, that my code isn't correct. But I don't understand, where?

Comment: I think I will defened $incomeDepositTax = 0; before loop. And in loop I need $incomeDepositTax += without $incomeDepositTax =

Comment: If you have more info, please add it to your question (using the question's "edit" button, just under the little blue tags). Don't bury extra details in the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop, as the formula is a straightforward calculation.

You have a couple of errors in your sum. Try:

```
$incomeDepositDay = $totalSum * $percent / ($typePerm *100);
$incomeDepositTax = $percent/(100 * $typePerm) * ($totalSum * $i + ($i - 1) * $incomeDepositDay * (1 - 13/100));
```

Comment: But as I understand sum in Math I need to get sum all days. For example I have 230 days. I get two sums - the first day and the last day. Don't all period.

Comment: The sum is over ICD(1) in the printed formula, not ICD(k).

Comment: And if I need to get ICD(k) exactly.I must be use the loop.

Comment: But you don't need ICD(k), just ICD(1).

Comment: No, I need. I count deposit income with tax.

Comment: Well the formula you've given says that you don't. The author has used a strange notation - there is no index on the sigma, and no index is used inside the sigma, which makes the sigma pointless. But that's what they've written.